# Which knot is this?

Tags: knot-theory

I am trying to figure out which [knot](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/4/49/Agalloch_Serpent_Sphere.jpg) this is. Is it a prime knot or a composite knot?

[image]

If I am counting correctly, there are 8 crossings in this image. Is this knot 8_16 shown [here](http://www.katlas.org/wiki/Knot_table_-_eight_crossings)?

[image]

edit: I am starting to think this is [8_18](http://www.katlas.org/w/images/4/42/8_18.gif).

[image]

P.S. This the cover of Agalloch's The Serpent & The Sphere Album.

Answer (score 10):

This is a [torus knot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Torus_knot), namely [T(4,3)](http://www.katlas.org/wiki/T(4,3)), also known as [$8_{19}$](http://www.katlas.org/wiki/8_19).

[image: The katlas image of the knot T(4,3).]

Being a (nontrivial) torus knot, it is prime.

Answer (score 5):

(Troposphere has already answered this question, but I thought I'd show off a tool you can use to identify knots.)

[KnotFolio](https://kmill.github.io/knotfolio/) is an online program where you can draw knots, and if it's prime and has few enough crossings, in most cases it can identify it.

I quickly drew the general path of the knot and used the crossing change tool until it matched your knot:

[image: crudely drawn knot]

And then it identified the only possible prime candidate:

[image: identification]

Clicking on the [8_19](http://katlas.math.toronto.edu/wiki/8_19) link, we see that one of the images in the gallery matches the knot more or less exactly:

[image: thumbnail]

So it's identified!

The common name for this knot is the ***true lover's knot***.

Comment: That's a legendary drawing.